# Spring MVC invalid Date Format error message not showing

Tags: java, spring, validation, date, spring-mvc

I'm having trouble regarding Date validation in Spring MVC 3

ClientForm.java

```
 public class ClientForm
 {
      private Date bday = new Date();

      //Getters and setters
 }
```

In my Controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@Valid ClientForm form, BindingResult result)
{
    if(result.hasErrors())
    {
        return "client.form";
    }

    return "redirect:search";
}
```

messages.properties

```
client.search.notnumber=Search value must be a number
typeMismatch.java.util.Date = Invalid date
```

jsp

```
<form:form action="save.html" method="post" commandName="clientForm">
    <form:input path="bday" cssClass="date-pick dp-applied" />
    <form:errors path="bday" element="label" cssClass="error"/>
</form:form>
```

***Other validation messages in 'messages.properties' works fine
but when i intentionally typed an invalid date (i.e. 111/12/2011)***

i got this error message

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>   Field error in object 'clientForm' on field 'bday': rejected value [21/05e/2011]; codes [typeMismatch.clientForm.bday,typeMismatch.bday,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [clientForm.bday,bday]; arguments []; default message [bday]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'bday'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Unable to convert value "21/05e/2011" from type 'java.lang.String' to type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "21/05e/2011" is malformed at "e/2011"]
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:359)
>       org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:275)
>       org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
>       org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
>       org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:344)
>       org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:272)
>       org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81)
>       org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>       org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
>   root cause
>   org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>   Field error in object 'clientForm' on field 'bday': rejected value [21/05e/2011]; codes [typeMismatch.clientForm.bday,typeMismatch.bday,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [clientForm.bday,bday]; arguments []; default message [bday]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'bday'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Unable to convert value "21/05e/2011" from type 'java.lang.String' to type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "21/05e/2011" is malformed at "e/2011"]
>       org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doBind(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:810)
>       org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:359)
>       org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:153)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:359)
>       org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:275)
>       org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
>       org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
>       org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:344)
>       org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:272)
>       org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81)
>       org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>       org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)

Answer (score 0):

This is a binding exception. Have you defined a binder? If yes, have you registered an editor for dates? Perhaps you should check that editor, you may have a typo there... where is that 'e' in the date coming from? It seems like a conversion error to me.

Comment: I intentionally put that 'e' in the date, i was trying to make spring show my error message in date validations